# Do i have to keep the MAIN inside my workspace and its view in order to merge files from a release branch? [Perforce]

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

So lets say i have the following directory:

```
- Dlls
- Globals
- App1
- App2
```

Where "Globals" and "Dlls" are sources shared between App1 and App2..
Now lets say i have an apllication called "Application 01" which consists of the folder App1, Globals and Dlls.

I can make the following workspace view..

```
//depot/release_1.0/App1/...  //workspace/Application01/release_1.0/App1/...
//depot/release_1.0/Dlls/...  //workspace/Application01/release_1.0/Dlls/...
//depot/release_1.0/Globals/...  //workspace/Application01/release_1.0/Globals/...
```

And it is all good..
i can sync, edit and work with the files as expected...

The release_1.0 has been launched and i want to propagate the changes to my MAIN.
Apparently i can't merge to my MAIN because its not in my client view...

However i do not want to keep MAIN inside my Workspace local directory...
Otherwise i'd need to have the following view:

```
//depot/release_1.0/App1/...  //workspace/Application01/release_1.0/App1/...
//depot/release_1.0/Dlls/...  //workspace/Application01/release_1.0/Dlls/...
//depot/release_1.0/Globals/...  //workspace/Application01/release_1.0/Globals/...
//depot/MAIN/App1/...  //workspace/Application01/MAIN/App1/...
//depot/MAIN/Dlls/...  //workspace/Application01/MAIN/Dlls/...
//depot/MAIN/Globals/...  //workspace/Application01/MAIN/Globals/...
```

Is this is the only way i could merge the changes to Main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the *destination* of your integration to be in your Workspace view.  So, when integrating to Main, switch to your Workspace View that just contains Main, that way you don't need to "mix" views.

Comment: And so it's the Main's view that will tell which files shall be integrated and which files shouldn't, right?  
  
I think I got it!
Thanks!

Comment: When you do an integrate you're opening the files "for integrate". So those files need to be in view.  The source files (those in your release_1.0) don't need to be in view.  If something that should be integrated is not in view, you'll get an error (so you don't need to worry about missing integrating files based on the view).